# restart ios background service after app killed

Tags: ios, service, background

If I have a service running in the background in my iOS app and someone kills the app (force closes)  then the service does not restart automatically (I have not checked that but seems logical). Is there any way to have an app that does not allow the user to kill the service? Or that restarts the service automatically, even if the user kills it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can, have a look at [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html).

Some apps are allowed to run in background, see part **Background Execution and Multitasking** of link above. It depends on what your app will do.

You can still ask for last-minute tasks when you'll enter in background, as you can see in the link above.

But anyway, once you are killed, it's over.

Hope it helps !